# How to get an iframe colorbox to scroll on an iPad with iOS 6

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I am using iframe colorboxes all over a site I have developed. They work fine but the major problem is that they don't scroll in iOS 6 (or any iOS that I can tell). I have tried many solutions online but none of them work 100%. The closest I got was the setTimeout one but that one has a bug that kept shooting me to the top.

Does anyone have a good solution for this issue?

Comment: You scroll in an iframe on an iPad using two fingers.

Comment: That doesn't work. At least it doesn't in the colorbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this hour, I'm solving for this issue using iScroll4 for iPad/Pod/Phone, as iOS does not support `position:fixed`.

Edit:
Child Page (iFramed from parent)

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="scroller-parent"><!-- position:absolute -->
    <div id="scroller"><!-- position:relative -->
    ... content of scrollable iFrame content ...
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share how you implemented iScroll4 in combination with the Colorbox to be able to scroll on an iPad?

Comment: It appears to work but I'm having an issue where it bounces around and doesn't stop where I stop scrolling. I'm trying to find the answer through iScroll.

Comment: Look at 'momentum'. You may also want to use 'lockDirection' to keep your page from scrolling diagonally.

Comment: I'll check it out. It kind of bounces/snaps back. It's very hard to scroll all the way to the bottom of a page.

Comment: Ok. If you're describing a "problem" where you have to hold the content and drag it up to see the bottom (only to lose sight of it when you release -- because it snaps back down...that's probably just a CSS padding/margin-bottom that needs adjusted in `scroller-parent`. Easy way to find out: `scroller-parent { padding-bottom:500px }`

Comment: The problem you're describing is correct. I added the CSS you suggested but it's still happening

Comment: I'm not sure if you have any javascript interacting with your content height, or if your iFrames are all the same size. I can tell you that I've used something like this: `$('#scroller').css('min-height',($('#scroller').height()+500+'px'));` to find out where my CSS problems were. If the height, or position of `parent` changes it does effect where `scroller` feels is the correct stopping point. If you have a working page going, I could probably find the snag.

Answer (score 1):

This was a known issue in iOS5 but should have been resolved in iOS6.  Certainly a site I developed recently using colorbox no longer has any scrolling issues

Comment: Do you have a site I can try it on?